# How to select first four letter of the column Distinct by select query in mysql?

Tags: mysql

To make it clear, I have a column named PartyCode in the party table.
It contains codes like

```
AAAA0, AAAA1, AAAA2, AAAA3...
ABAB0, ABAB1, ABAB2..
```

So what I want is first 4 letters of code and it should not be repeated ie. AAAA, ABAB.

I have tried it with `DISTINCT` and `SUBSTR` keyword but unable to do this.
So I want to know that is that possible to do in one select query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "group by" instead of distinct:

```
select LEFT(partyCode,4) as code from parties group by code;
```

Distinct works too:

```
select distinct LEFT(partyCode,4) as code from parties;
```

So I don't quite know where your problem is.

Comment: As per my experiment `distinct` is working with single column to fetch while `group by` with multiple columns too.<br/>

`SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(PartyCode, 4) AS pcode, PartyName, SecondCode, MobileNo, Address, Category, Dat, GrandTotal, PartySrNo FROM partytable WHERE Category='S' ORDER BY PartySrNo DESC `
<br/>
This query returns the result but not the distinct one, i mean code is repeated in it.<br/>

@adder please check out the query if there is mistake<br/>

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT means different in ANY of the columns following in the select, so you will get multiple same party codes. The better way for you will be to use GROUP BY, and to use aggregation functions like FIRST LAST SUM AVG, MIN, MAX on the other columns which are not part of the group by.